# Is Spotify broken at the moment? Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, spotify

Tried removing and installing again, but no matter what I can't get it to work. "Spotify is already running, but not responding. Please close it and try again" regardless of what I do. Tried removing the package completely and getting it again, but same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try removing the Spotify settings and cache folders (~/.config/spotify and ~/.cache/spotify, respectively).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it did not however work. I opened Spotify after doing so, and the window just freezes and forces me to quit - after opening it again, the same error occurs

Comment: What version of Spotify are you running?

Comment: Are there actual versions? I've added their official repository and used `sudo apt-get install spotify-client` to fetch it?

Comment: You can see the client version in the about dialog, or with newer versions by running spotify --version from the command line. Anyways you are probably running 0.9.17, try the 1.x beta: https://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-Announcements/Spotify-Client-1-x-beta-for-Linux-has-been-released/m-p/1147294

Comment: I have no clue why, but running spotify --version fixed the issue. It opened spotify and it ran better than ever... Thanks? Unintentional fix, haha.